# Redirection of haproxy inside pfSense is not correct

Tags: haproxy

I want to start use haproxy inside pfsense but redirection is not working entirely.

My haproxy configuration file is this:

```
# Automaticaly generated, dont edit manually.
# Generated on: 2024-01-30 08:58
global
    maxconn         1000
    log         /var/run/log    local0  info
    stats socket /tmp/haproxy.socket level admin  expose-fd listeners
    uid         80
    gid         80
    nbthread            1
    hard-stop-after     15m
    chroot              /tmp/haproxy_chroot
    daemon
    tune.ssl.default-dh-param   2048
    server-state-file /tmp/haproxy_server_state

frontend ha_frontend
    bind            192.168.1.1:10000 name 192.168.1.1:10000   ssl crt-list /var/etc/haproxy/ha_frontend.crt_list  
    mode            http
    log         global
    option          log-separate-errors
    option          httplog
    option          http-keep-alive
    timeout client      30000
    acl         msggw_acl   var(txn.txnpath) -m beg -i /api/asl/msggw
    acl         aclcrt_ha_frontend  var(txn.txnhost) -m reg -i ^([^\.]*)\.myplace\.com(:([0-9]){1,5})?$
    http-request set-var(txn.txnpath) path
    http-request set-var(txn.txnhost) hdr(host)
    use_backend msggw2_ipvANY  if  msggw_acl aclcrt_ha_frontend
    use_backend nginx_new_ipvANY  if   aclcrt_ha_frontend

backend msggw2_ipvANY
    mode            http
    id          102
    log         global
    option          log-health-checks
    http-check      send meth GET
    timeout connect     30000
    timeout server      30000
    retries         3
    load-server-state-from-file global
    option          httpchk
    server          msggw2 38.22.112.236:5151 id 103 ssl check-ssl check inter 1000  verify none 

backend nginx_new_ipvANY
    mode            http
    id          104
    log         global
    option          log-health-checks
    http-check      send meth GET
    timeout connect     30000
    timeout server      30000
    retries         3
    load-server-state-from-file global
    option          httpchk
    server          nginx_new 38.22.112.236:443 id 105 ssl check-ssl check inter 1000  verify none
```

When I use https://vm2.myplace.com:10000/ in browser, redirect is correct. I am redirected to server 38.22.112.236 , where on 443 port, nginx is running.

But when I use https://vm2.myplace.com:10000/api/asl/msggw , I want to be redirected to server 38.22.112.236 port 5151 which is .NET Core service. Instead of correct redirection I will get Status 503 Service is Unavailable - No server is available to handle this request.

BTW when I fill https://38.22.112.236:5151/api/asl/msggw in browser , response status code is 200. And content of response is something like this

```
    "gRPC": [
        {
            "name": "gRPC - ...................................",
            "pattern": ".........................",
            "order": 0
        },
     .....
```

Why it doesn't work for me msggw2 redirection even though backend server is running and returns 200 Status code ?

Log from haproxy is here:

```
Jan 30 10:30:52 pfSense haproxy[78524]: Health check for server msggw2_ipvANY/msggw2 failed, reason: Layer7 invalid response, info: "TCPCHK got an empty response at step 2", check duration: 198ms, status: 0/2 DOWN.
```

Both servers can handle SSL requests.

Thank you for any advice that can help me , solve this issue.